# Login using Google link is broken?

Tags: bug, login

I got this when trying to log in to Server Fault today (I don't know why I'm logged in here, and not there):

[image: 400 Bad Request]

Is something wrong with this? I had this problem a while back as well (about a week ago), but the website logged me in from a previous session, so I dismissed it.

Comment: Can you access https://accounts.google.com ?

Comment: Happens only with SF?

Comment: @nicael it appears to be a problem on all stack exchange sites.